# right hand to God - what does this mean?

Tags: meaning

From the science fiction movie [**Dreamcatcher**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamcatcher_(2003_film)) (2003):

> — Nine miles to Hole in the Wall.
>   — I think I can manage it.
>   — I'll bring the snowmobile back and get you both. Now, Pete, you listen to me. Don't go back to the car for beer. Stay with her. Keep her warm.
>   — **Right hand to God**, Dr. D.

What exactly does this expression mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I swear/promise."

It's common practice in the US to place one's hand on a Bible and/or raise one's right hand when making an oath, such as being sworn into office (like the president) or when testifying in court.

You may also hear "God as my witness" or "May God smite me."